# Django views select from db list of datefield

Tags: python, django

I am sorry if this is a silly question, because after reading some documentation I was able to render every model field in my view, but I am stuck with a list of DateField label...

So in my model I have a :

```
date_realization = models.DateField(_('Realised in'),
                                     default=timezone.now)
```

Field, but I don't know why I can't select it in my views.py.
Well, I mean I have articles and each article has a date_realization. I want to get the list of those date and render it into the context method but I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone has a clue about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a list of `date_realization` for all articles you could do:

```
date_realization_for_articles = Article.objects.values_list('date_realization',
                                                            flat=True).distinct()
```

django doc for [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Comment: I was stuck for so long because I didn't know how to specifically search for it. Thank you so much man !

Comment: Haha, I tried but I couldn't come up with something that make google return `value_list` either!